# How to remove first few carracter if it is appear?

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have to do next thing!
Here is for exmaple next text:

```
0  ONAIR: PolinaGhffith RalphGood-SOS OhginaIMix
```

I ned to extract just

```
PolinaGhffith RalphGood-SOS OhginaIMix
```

But the problem is that sometimes text is showed without `0  ONAIR:`
 I try with next code but it won't do it this job allways!

```
sed -e 's/_..........: //' -e 's/\t//g' -e 's/_//g'
```

I know that it delete all tabulators and "_" caracters, and it omits `0  ONAIR:` but it won;t work every time :(
Thx!

Comment: Maybe you want to reread the answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709767/how-to-remove-caracters-like-form-a-grep-results-with-grep-awk-or-sed as what is shown there can easily be applied here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

**grep**

```
kent$  echo "0  ONAIR: PolinaGhffith RalphGood-SOS OhginaIMix"|grep -Po '(?<=: ).*$'
PolinaGhffith RalphGood-SOS OhginaIMix
```

**awk**

```
kent$  echo "0  ONAIR: PolinaGhffith RalphGood-SOS OhginaIMix"|awk -F': ' '{print $2}'
PolinaGhffith RalphGood-SOS OhginaIMix
```

**sed**

```
kent$  echo "0  ONAIR: PolinaGhffith RalphGood-SOS OhginaIMix"|sed 's/^.*: //'
PolinaGhffith RalphGood-SOS OhginaIMix
```